# BasicDataSource commit not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I have configured the data source and set auto commit false.

```
<bean id="dbDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"> 
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${widget.database.driver}" /> 
        <property name="url" value="${widget.database.url}" /> 
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" /> 
        <property name="accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed" value="true" />
        <property name="username" value="${widget.database.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${widget.database.password}" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="${widget.database.maxActive}" /> 
        <property name="maxIdle" value="${widget.database.maxIdle}" /> 
    </bean>
```

In my DAO clas i have done it.

```
    public void insertDIMFactToDB(WidgetJobOutput jobOutput) throws DataAccessException {
        int rowsInserted=0;     
    try {
        logger.info("Databse insert for DIMCODE " + jobOutput.getDimCode() + " having DIMFACT value as : " + + jobOutput.getDimFact());
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        Object[] params = new Object[] { 
                    jobOutput.getDimCode(), 
                    jobOutput.getDimFact()
                                };
        rowsInserted = jdbcTemplate.update(DBConstants.INS_WIDGET_HRLY_DATA, 
                        params);
        //logger.info("Successfully inserted/updated " + rowsInserted +  " in DB");

    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        throw e ;
    }
    // commit everything 
    try {
    DataSourceUtils.getConnection(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource()).commit();
        logger.info("Successfully inserted/updated " + rowsInserted +  " in DB");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error("Error Occured while commiting data into DB:-"+ ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));
    }


    }
```

But it is neither throwing any exception nor commiting the data. 
Please help me to find the bug.Thanks in advance

Comment: Show the rest of the code around the `commit()`.

Comment: Why are you even working directly with data source if you are using `spring-jdbc`? You should be shielded from JDBC stuff.

Comment: added all the code ...

Comment: @Pavel : please clarify what should i do then

Comment: You should be using `JdbcTemplate` or `SimpleJdbcTemplate`, which are Spring's facades so that you don't need to work with JDBC classes yourself. For manual transactions you should use `TransactionTemplate` (of course much better would be annotation driven transaction management).

Comment: And btw. when using DBCP, every call to `dataSource.getConnection()` is taking a new connection from the pool (hence your commit is on different connection than your queries). You should strictrly use Spring's `DataSourceUtils` if you really need to access connections. Of course that will work only in conjunction with transaction management.

Comment: And finally - in your case the manual `commit` is absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: I have also used   DataSourceUtils.getConnection(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource()).commit();
Still nthing works.

Comment: Is this inference based after executing JUnits ? if yes, the methods need to be annotated with @Rollback(false) to see the actual results in database.

Answer (score 1):

We'll need to see the DAO source as well, but it seems likely you are committing a different connection to the one you are executing your SQL on.

```
dataSource.getConnection().commit();
```

will get the next available connection from your pool, which will not be the one you have just used for your update ( as that one is probably still in use ).

Comment: You could try DataSourceUtils.getConnection(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource()).commit(); Not tested this though ......

Comment: show your updated code  please. By the way - I'm not sure that defining your jdbcTemplate instance outside the scope of this method is a good idea, although it's hard to tell without a little more context

Comment: also,does the log statement indicate that any rows were successfully updated / inserted?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32423/discussion-between-subha-sankar-and-davehowes)

Comment: I'm afraid that's all I can offer - it looks ok to me. Next step ( if this was me ) would be to use a debugger to see if the connection that is being taken from the jdbcTemplate is the same at the point of insert/ update and commit.

Answer (score 1):

Below statement will give you a new connection and will try to commit on that connection. However you want to commit the same connection which was used to run the query.

```
JdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection().commit();
```

Try using old school way of commit if you want to use AutoCommit as false in your datasource property config

```
   Connection conn = null;
   PreparedStatement  stmt  = null;
   boolean result = false;
   try{
       conn = getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection();
       stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
      // stmt.setString(1, "ABC");
              result = stmt.executeUpdate();
            conn.commit();          
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // LOGGER.error();
        }finally{
            if(stmt != null){
                try {
                    stmt.close();

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                     // LOGGER.error();
                }
            }
        }
```